# script error bash ( error:*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used)

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

# Decrypt function
function decrypt {
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $hash | sed 's/988sn1/83unasa/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/4d298d/9999/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/3i8dqos82/873h4d/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/4n9Ls/20X/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/912oijs01/i7gg/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/k32jx0aa/n391s/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/nI72n/YzF1/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/82ns71n/2d49/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/JGcms1a/zIm12/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/MS9/4SIs/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/Ymxj00Ims/Uso18/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/sSi8Lm/Mit/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/9su2n/43n92ka/g')
    Mzns7293sk=$(echo $MzSaas7k | sed 's/ggf3iunds/dn3i8/g')
    MzSaas7k=$(echo $Mzns7293sk | sed 's/uBz/TT0K/g')

    flag=$(echo $MzSaas7k | base64 -d | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:$salt)
}

# Variables
var="9M"
salt=""
hash="VTJGc2RHVmtYMTl2ZnYyNTdUeERVRnBtQWVGNmFWWVUySG1wTXNmRi9rQT0K"

# Base64 Encoding Example:
#        $ echo "Some Text" | base64

for i in {1..28}

do

    var=$(echo $var | base64)
    
    if [[ $i == 28 ]]
    then
        salt=$(echo $var | wc -c)
    fi    
done

# Check if $salt is empty
if [[ ! -z "$salt" ]]
then
    decrypt
    echo $flag
else
    exit 1
fi
```

error:*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
140546881238400:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:

the exercise:  Create a "For" loop that encodes the variable "var" 28 times in "base64". The number of characters in the 28th hash is the value that must be assigned to the "salt" variable.
code made by me :

```
for i in {1..28}

do

    var=$(echo $var | base64)

    if [[ $i == 28 ]]
    then
        salt=$(echo $var | wc -c)
    fi    
done
```

Comment: The error message does not come from bash. Most likely it comes from `decrypt`, and your problem is not bash-related.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in case you are stuck. Make sure to delete “salt” in the #Variables tab. We will set the salt in the loop.

```
#Variables
var="9M"
hash="VTJGc2RHVmtYMTl2ZnYyNTdUeERVRnBtQWVGNmFWWVUySG1wTXNmRi9rQT0K"


# Base64 Encoding Example:
#        $ echo "Some Text" | base64

# <- For-Loop here

for ((i = 0 ; i < 28 ; i++)); do
        echo "Try number $i"
        var=$(echo $var | base64)
        echo $var | wc -c
        salt=$(echo $var | wc -c)

done
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be right, but I had to make a workaround too.

This might do the trick:

```
salt=$((${#var}+1))
# ${#var} counts the length and you have to add 1 to make the exercise work.
```

This way it'll still show you the warning, but if you copy the last line, that'll be your answer.